# Histogram doesn't show all bins

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have data that runs from values of 0 all the way to 40000.

When I plot the histogram of this data using the Histogram[] command I get this:

[image]

I've split the data up into those that are below 1500 and above 1500 to get the following plots below:

Below 1500:

[image]

Above 1500: 
[image]

For the plot below 1500, the data runs up till 120. Is there a way to make it show up till 1500 instead?

Also, are there other interesting ways to plot this data for better visualisation? It seems to be very centre-ed around 0, thus the plots not showing the higher bins.

Comment: try `PlotRange -> {{0,1500}, All}`?

Comment: For your particular application would it make sense to look at the log or the square root of the variable of interest?  (I'm not understanding why you say that the data "seems to be very centre-ed around 0".  Do you just mean that there are more small values than large values?

Comment: Have a closer look that the bin specification for `Histogram` in the documentation. Also, `PlotRange -> {Full, Automatic}` will also help.